# update con doble condicion en c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Requiero actualizar un campo de un registro en mi base de datos sql usando dos condiciones

Estoy intentando hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
sql = "UPDATE detalle_pedido SET cant_ingresar = '" + Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxCantidadCargar.Text.Trim()) + "' where codigobarras = '" + codigo + "' AND idpedido='" + idpedido + "'";
```

pero no me lograr hacer la actualizacion.

Que debo modificar para poder hacerlo

Comment: Tira algun error este codigo? porque decis que no hace la actualizacion? el SQL resultante es correcto? podrias mostrarlo?

Comment: no me hace el update en la tabla, el valor esta como null y al finalizar el ciclo sigue asi

Comment: Y si pones ese update directo en la db lo hace? sin ver todo el codigo, los datos que estas pasando y la descripcion de la tabla es dificil ayudarte.

Comment: igual, me parece que te sobran unas comillas, cant_ingresar debe ser un numero, con lo cual esas comillas simples parecerian sobrar.

Comment: he realizado lo que me dices y aun asi sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices "Sql Server Profile" para que veas el sql resultante que se ejecuta. Con eso puedes tener una idea mas clara del porque no se actualiza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- transforma la variable, fuera de la actualizacion, asi verificas que tenga el tipo de datos correcto.

2.- puede que tengas algun problema con el uso de '' , te sugiero que uses un breakpoint de visual studio y verifiques los valores de las variables y veas como esta quedando la consulta, consultando el valor de la variable "sql".